# Cannot get Pyinstaller to create a standalone with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

Of, so my frustration levels have gotten to the point that I must reach out for assistance.

I have a single file that uses pandas to read a report and do some data manipulation. I have it completed and would like to create a stand alone exe for it.

Unfortunately, Pandas is not "out of the box" able to be used when you are creating an executable as i get an error stating : ModuleNotFoundErrer: No Module named 'pandas'

I went online and looked up solutions, and so far I have done ALL OF THIS:

Edited the EGTReport.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path


a = Analysis(['EGTReports.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\TW2020'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='EGTReports',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False )
```

And then I added the following to the pandas Hook:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2017-2019, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License with exception
# for distributing bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

# Pandas keeps Python extensions loaded with dynamic imports here.
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pandas._libs')

hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
                         'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype',
                         'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime',
                         'pandas._libs.skiplist']
```

Then opened up cmd into the directory that had my script and rand:

```
pyinstaller --onefile EGTReports.spec
```

and that produced this log:

```
130 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
130 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
130 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
140 INFO: UPX is not available.
150 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\TW2020',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\TW2020']
150 INFO: checking Analysis
185 INFO: Building because inputs changed
185 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
189 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
189 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6031 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6031 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
8509 INFO: Caching module hooks...
8534 INFO: Analyzing EGTReports.py
10060 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
13200 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
13200 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python          \\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
16145 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
22436 INFO: Loading module hooks...
22436 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
22439 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
22585 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
22594 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
22773 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
22775 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
23254 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
23254 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
23254 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
23254 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
23259 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
23259 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
23259 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
23264 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
23264 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
23269 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
23269 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
23269 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
23269 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
23274 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
23900 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
24350 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
24350 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
24909 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
25456 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
26609 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
26829 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
26840 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
27744 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
27744 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
27744 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
27744 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
28424 INFO: checking Tree
28544 INFO: checking Tree
28739 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
28800 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
28819 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
28829 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
28829 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
28839 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
28870 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
50560 INFO: Looking for eggs
50560 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32 \python37.dll
50560 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
50584 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\TW2020\build\EGTReports\warn-   EGTReports.txt
50860 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\TW2020\build\EGTReports\xref-EGTReports.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "EGTReports.spec", line 24, in <module>
dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
File "EGTReports.spec", line 6, in get_pandas_path
import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I am at a loss.. Any Idea on how to create an executable standalone from python using Pandas??

I am really not wanting to remove pandas and start from scratch rewriting my software and manually trying to draw out and manipulate an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I had to do this as well a while back for the same situation - I don't have the `noarchive=false`, `bootloader_ignore_signals=False` or `runtime_tmpdir=None` lines in my spec file though. Also - `# -*- mode: python -*-`. Rest is the same.

Comment: @Randor are you using virtual environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have problem with installation of pandas module.
Try to run command "pip install pandas" first may be your pandas package is not install.
then you can run pyinstaller.

However you can do additional things like setup settings follow below example:

Please fill "install_requires" whatever packages you want.

```
setup(
    name="abcd",
    version="1.0.0",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/realpython/reader",
    author="abcd",
    author_email="abcd.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ],
    packages=["reader"],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "pandas", "html2text", "importlib_resources", "typing"
    ],
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["abc=reader.__main__:main"]},
)
```

Comment: Hi j suman, please don't format your entire answer as code if part of it is not code.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am afraid I am not understanding where to put this code? and what to do, I am new to Python and am learning as I go.

Comment: How on earth does this answer the question? This is setup tools packaging not PyInstaller.